# How do I push data to a Polymer dom-repeat template?

Tags: javascript, polymer

Say I have the following code, which is a collection of cards with titles and text:

```
<template id="cardSetFoo" is="dom-bind">
  <template id="cardSet" is="dom-repeat" items="[[data]]">
    <paper-card>
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4>[[item.title]]</h4>
        [[item.text]]
      </div>
    </paper-card>
  </template>
</template>
```

And I want to populate the set of cards:

```
document.querySelector('#cardSet').push('data',[{'title':'Title','text':'Description'}]);
```

I keep getting **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined(…)** *(notify-path.html:476)*

Can anyone enlighten me on how to populate a dom-repeat template? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
var app = document.querySelector('#cardSetFoo');
if (!app.data) {
  app.data = [];
}
app.push('data', [{'title':'Title','text':'Description'}]);
```

Your dom-repeat code is incorrect. You have to use `item` to access array items inside the dom-repeat. You can use `as` attribute to give it a different name as below

```
<template id="cardSetFoo" is="dom-bind">
  <template id="cardSet" is="dom-repeat" items="[[data]]" as="card">
    <paper-card>
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4>[[card.title]]</h4>
        [[card.text]]
      </div>
    </paper-card>
  </template>
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks! I caught that myself and changed it to 'item' and was still getting the error. Unfortunately I get the same error with this though when selecting #cardSetFoo instead of #cardSet. Any thoughts?

Comment: Might be initialization issue. Try the edit I just submitted.